# how to iterate over generic interface in angular

Tags: angular

I'am relatively new to angular . I try to use genric interface in order to reuse pagination models from other models.
with code I can explain better.
here is my code for user model

```
export interface IUser{
id: string;
name: string;
email: string;
emailConfirmed: boolean;
twoFactorEnabled: boolean;
lockoutEnabled: boolean;
accessFailedCount: number;
role: string;
roleId: string;}
```

and this my pagination interface model

```
export interface IPagination<T> {
success: boolean;
pageIndex: number;
pageSize: number;
count: number;
data: T[];}
```

and this is my component ts class

```
users:IPagination<IUser[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {this.http.get("https://localhost:7105/api/auth/admin/User").subscribe((response:IPagination<IUser[]>)=>{this.users=response;},error=>{console.log(error);})}
```

everythings works fine except in component's html when I try to iterate over data this error comes

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you need `this.users=response.data`? (I imagine that your API return an IPagination). NOTE: Then we use httpClient.get It doesn't matter the "inferface" we use. Remember, Angular transpile to javaScript. The "interface" only help us to check errors in code, but not "force" to cast the value in the way we want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in casting to interface in api call . here's correct way to call API

> ngOnInit(): void {
> this.http.get("https://localhost:7105/api/auth/admin/User").subscribe((response:IPagination)=>{
> this.users=response;
> },error=>{
> console.log(error);
> })
> }

Now it's working with this code sample in component html

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of users.data">
    <li>{{item.email}}</li>
```

But still I'm not sure if this is a correct way or not ?